# Need something similar to Portmanteau Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_n,Y_n,n\geq 1$ be sequences of real random variables such that
$$
\int f(X_n)\,d\mathbb{P}-\int f(Y_n)\,d\mathbb{P}\to 0
$$
for all bounded and continuous functions $f$.

For which sets $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ does it hold that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n\in A)-\mathbb{P}(Y_n\in A)\to 0 ?
$$
I realize that I cannot use the Portmanteau theorem. Are there any additional assumptions that I would need for this to work?

What about the special case where $X_n=x_n+Z$ and $Y_n=y_n+Z$ with numerical sequences $x_n,y_n,n\geq 1$ with $x_n-y_n\to 0$?

Thank you

Comment: Just a minor counter-example: Let $X$ be a random variable with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[X=1/i]=1$. Define $X_n=X/n$ and $Y_n=0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  Then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$ but if we define $A = \{1/n : n \in \{1, 2, 3, …\}\}$ then $P[Y_n \in A]=0$ and $P[X_n \in A] =1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Another observation: If $Z$ has a continuous CDF and $X_n = x_n+Z$, $Y_n=y_n+Z$, $|x_n-y_n|\rightarrow 0$, then it can be shown $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|P[X_n\leq x] -P[Y_n\leq x]|=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Uniformly continuous, no?

Comment: That is the interesting part...the nice thing about continuous CDFs is that they are always uniformly continuous. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and find a positive integer $M$ so that $Z$ lies in the compact interval $[-M,M]$ with probability at least $1-\epsilon/2$.

Comment: By the way, I do not agree that $X_n=x_n+Z, Y_n=y_n+Z$, $x_n-y_n\rightarrow 0$ implies $E[f(X_n)-f(Y_n)]\rightarrow 0$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$. Take $Z=0$ and define $x_n=n, y_n=n+1/n$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  You can construct a bounded continuous function $f$ such that $f(x_n)=0, f(y_n)=1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Nevertheless I would agree if you add the additional assumption that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}, \{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are themselves bounded sequences.